# React Navigation auth flow. Auth navigator is visible before Main navigator for short period of time

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-navigation

I am using firebase authentication for user authentication and react-navigation to render different navigators based on user state. In Firebase.js I listen for auth state change and set state accordingly. The problem is, when I set user data and hide splash screen (npm package *react-native-splash-screen*) Auth stack can still be seen before Main stack is rendered. I want to ask a question, how could this be solved?

**Firebase.js** context provider

```
class Firebase extends React.Component {
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            user: null,
            userDoc: null,
            isLoading: true,
        };
    }
    usersRef = firestore().collection('Users');
    componentDidMount() {
        const { isLoading, user } = this.state;
        auth().onAuthStateChanged(res => {
            if (res) {
                this.usersRef?.doc(res.uid).onSnapshot(async snapshot => {
                    this.setState(
                        {
                            user: res,
                            userDoc: snapshot.exists ? snapshot.data() : null,
                            isLoading:false
                        },
                        () => SplashScreen.hide();
                    );
                });
            } else {
                this.setState(
                    {
                        user: null,
                        isUserSubscribed: false,
                        isLoading: false,
                    },
                    () => SplashScreen.hide();
                );
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**RootNavigator.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import MainNavigatorWrapper from '../MainNavigator';
import AuthNavigator from '../AuthNavigator';
import { useFirebase } from '../../context';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const RootNavigator = () => {
    const { user } = useFirebase();
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator}>
                {!user ? (
                    <Stack.Screen name="Auth" component={AuthNavigator} />
                ) : (
                    <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={MainNavigatorWrapper} />
                )}
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this because I was looking for a solution to the same problem. I came up with a hack. I'm sure there is a better way to fix this issue but I haven't figured it out yet. This is what I did.

In App.js I return this:

```
export default function App() {

    const [dataLoaded, setDataLoaded] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        async function loadApp() {
            try {
                await SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync()
                // DO APP LOADING STUFF HERE
            } catch (err) {
                console.warn(err)
            } finally {
                setDataLoaded(true)
            }
        }
        loadApp()
    }, [])

    if (!dataLoaded){
        return null
    }
 
   return (
      <AuthenticationContextProvider>
         <Navigation />
      </AuthenticationContextProvider>
   )
}
```

As you can see, I'm using expo's `SplashScreen` API. So, the trick was to hide everything behind the Splash Screen until the authentication was resolved.

My Navigation component looks like this:

```
    export const Navigation = () => {
   const { isAuthenticated } = useContext(AuthenticationContext)

    const splashHiddenRef = useRef(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        // splash screen hasn't been hidden yet and authentication has already been determined
        if (!splashHiddenRef.current && isAuthenticated !== null) {
            // delay the splash screen from hiding to quick. Otherwise, the AuthenticationNavigator
            // will flash before the AppNavigator is shown (when user is already authenticated on load)
            setTimeout(() => {
                hideAsync()
            }, 1000)
        }
    }, [isAuthenticated])

   return <NavigationContainer>{isAuthenticated ? <AppNavigator /> : <AccountNavigator />}</NavigationContainer>
}
```

As you can see, I delay the hiding of the Splash Screen for 1 second. If there was a slow network connection this may not work. I'm not certain. For now, it's kind of a hack that I'm messing with.

**What I tried prior to this hack:**

It didn't work before, but `isAuthenticated` in my context has an initial value of null. When the app loads, once the authentication is resolved, this value becomes either true or false (never to be null again). So, I assumed once the auth was NOT null then it should load the correct navigator without the flicker of the auth navigator. I believe it has something to do with the initial rendering of the layout. The `SpashScreen` API solves this issues like this:

[Expo SplashScreen](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v41.0.0/sdk/splash-screen/#usage)

The problem is this isn't a very good example. To my knowledge, you can't use `onLayout` in a navigator. I think you can only use it in subclasses of `React.View`.

Perhaps someone can provide a better solution.....this worked for me.....for now